# Resolve template with a nested class

Tags: c++

```
class Foo // Empty class
{
};

template <class T> // Abstract class
class Comparator
{
public:
  virtual ~Comparator() {}

  virtual bool operator()(const T& e1, const T& e2) = 0;
};

// Mother class that contains a map and some other methods that I did not copied here
template <class Key, class Value, class Comparator = std::less<Key> >
class Mother
{
private:
  std::map<Key, Value, Comparator> data_;
};

// Daughter class that wants to use its own Comparator (called Nested)
class Daughter : public Mother<Foo, Foo, typename Daugher::Nested>
{
public:
  class Nested : public Comparator<Foo>
  {
    bool operator()(const Foo& e1, const Foo& e2)
    {
      return true; // Not my real code. However, what would it mean to always return true in this kind of operation ? std::map would be pretty unusable, i guess ?
    }
  }
};
```

This code won't compile as G++ cannot access `Nested` as I did not solve the templates of Daugher before accessing Nested. It may work if I wrote `Daughter<?????>::Nested`, I think. However, I'd need to give `Daughter` its own comparator, that I could not access because that would need I access it with `Daughter<?????>`, and recursively.

I am pretty sure that what I am trying to do is invalid in C++, as I should resolve `Daughter` before accessing its Nested class. However, my `Nested` class is pretty simple and doesn't need its upper class to be really defined.

So, I could declare `Nested` outside `Daughter`, calling it `FooComparator` or something, but it seemed cleaner to say that it was `Nested` inside `Daughter`.

Please note that I do not wish to declare an `operator<` inside `Foo` because in my real case it represents cities, and I don't think it is very clean to declare an `operator<` for cities.

Is there a cleaner option so that I could declare my Daughter class and ask it to use its own comparator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually to me a good solution would be to implement the `FooComparator` as you say, because if the comparator pertains to `Foo`, so it does not really make sense to have it within `Daughter`. What if you need to compare `Foo` again but from another class? However, maybe can you have your comparator implemented within Foo if you absolutely want this comparator class within a class:

```
struct Foo {
  struct Comp: Comparator<Foo> {
    ...
  };
};

class Daughter: public Mother<Foo, Foo, Foo::Comp>
{
  ...
};
```

Comment: And possibly, `using Nested = Foo::Comp;` inside `Daughter`.